# I have 3 notifications in notification bar (Android/Java) and I have to reply one of them. How remote input knows to which notification I am replying

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications

Data in pending intent was set while each notification was created. In broadcast receiver I could only have reference of message values. Some guys discuss about reply to multiple users but no one has solution. How whatsapp achieve this?

the remote input and key works for last message only but what about other users.
Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using single pending intent each time. Now I initialize it every time before notification is created. Now I get the corresponding data in broadcast receiver from remote input/intent.